# Moment js add time and increment it

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am sending hours and minute in format "12:02" and timezone as "GMT". I  want to set hours and minutes in moment js

```
var timeFormatSecond = moment.tz(zoneList[secondTimeZone])
timeFormatSecond = timeFormatSecond.set({
  'hour' : secondDateTime.getHours(),
  'minute' : secondDateTime.getMinutes()
});
```

But after couple of minutes when i do `timeFormatSecond.format('HH:mm')`

then it give hours and minutes what i have sent earlier.

Comment: Where do you set secondDateTime ? It's probably just a sync issue on this variable

Comment: secondDateTime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);

Comment: secondDateTime is global variable

Comment: OK. Since secondDateTime is a global variable, you should **update** it's value everytime you want to update your time; or else you'll keep having to refresh your timer with outdated valuies